# Salesforce Visualforce PDF page break in tables

Tags: pdf, html-table, visualforce, page-break

I have a Visualforce page rendered as pdf. The page contains multiline table. I set the

> page-break-inside: avoid;

css property to tr tags already. The borders are duplicated on the bottom and the top of the pages on page breaks. With 90% zoom level I see dots, with 100% I see the horizontal line on the rendered PDF. What is the solution the break tables between pages? Thanks is advance, Chris

[horizontal line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRX0I.jpg)

[horizontal dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1esOH.jpg)